# Add images and require file of Titanium Alloy

Tags: titanium, titanium-alloy

I'm trying to require the file from the file userManager.js index.js as seen in the photos. But it gives me error:

```
[ERROR] Script Error Could not find module: app / cloud / UserManager
```

I tried to change:

```
var user = require('userManager');
var user = require('/userManager');
var user = require('cloud/userManager');
var user = require('./cloud/userManager');
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All resources in the app developed with Alloy must be under the folder:

`/assets`